# How to add a new url to the routes.js file in an already existing Node.js project built using locomotive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, locomotivejs

```
module.exports = function routes() {
this.root('pages#main');
this.match('/status', 'pages#status');

this.resources('paper');
this.resources('tempform');
};
```

How to add a new url suppose "paper/domain"  to my application?

Can someone please explain how I can add this? I have read the Locomotive guide but couldn't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Locomotive routes are configured in `config/routes.js`.

```
this.match('pages/:home', { controller: 'PageController', action: 'show' });
```

And then in the `controllers` directory create a new file with

```
var PageController = new Controller();
module.exports = PageController;
PageController.show = function() {
  this.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the LocomotiveJS guide: http://locomotivejs.org/guide/namespaces/

You can use namespaces to group several controllers under a namespace (e.g. example.com/namespace/). In your case, you would want something like

```
this.namespace('paper', function() {
  this.match('domain', 'yourController#yourAction');
});
```